# If a graph has 57 edges, what is the minimum number of vertices?

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a formula or something for this? I know there is one for finding the minimum number of edges in a n-vetex graph, but I can't find anything related to finding the minimum number of vertices give the number of edges.

Comment: Can you do it with less than 58? One vertex with 57 edges and 57 vertices with one edge?

Comment: Yes, but the degree of the vertices is not limited to only 2 though, so it should be less than the given number of edges.

Comment: Hint: think of complete graphs

Comment: Sorry about my comment. Every vertex connecting to every other makes the most sense. Should not comment without more thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** If a graph has $n$ vertices, then there are $\binom{n}{2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ distinct pairs of vertices, or $\binom{n}{2}$ possible edges. This means that a graph with $n$ vertices can have at most $\binom{n}{2}$ edges... can you use this information to solve your problem?